ENV for Wordpress
Hi im new to wordpress/php so apology in advance for such a noob question.
Just a little bit of context, I'm trying to do this custom stripe payment integration on a wordpress site that does something when a CPT is created, the integration is pretty easy and working just fine (not using any plugin - coded from scratch).
I straight-up coded this all in the functions.php of the child-theme of the site, the issue with the integration I did is that the secret-key is exposed in the functions.php and that's not good.
I'm a rails / node js dude, usually the solution to this is to use ENV (environment variables), does wordpress have that kind of feature? for hosting im using wpengine and it seems they don't have that option... so here  i am haha

The equivalent of Node would be PHP, not WordPress, you'd be best asking about PHP environment variables at stackoverflow ( probably already asked ) or checking at php.net, as for setting those variables those or secret management at your host, you'd be best asking WP Engine as that answer is specific and unique to them and your hosting plan

PHP files won't be downloadable over the internet anyway, and there are already secrets in wp-config.php if you want to put your API key in there, and if WPEngine supports editing it directly. Plus I'd guess lot of existing stripe integrations put their API keys in the database.

You should be able to set the variable in your .htaccess file and then pick it up using getenv() or any of the $_ENV, $_SERVER super globals. For instance adding SetEnv MY_SECRET_KEY "foobar" in your .htaccess. Note, that the .htaccess file of course should not be public readable.

As I don't know why rails prefer to store such secrets in an environment variable the answer might not be complete, but if the reason is to avoid having it in the code and therefor accessible to everybody with access to the code (via git or misconfigured web server), wordpress has two ways to do something similar

keep it in the DB. This is what most plugins will do. You are at risk if someone can get into you DB, but in that case you are in all kinds of other major trouble as well
wp-config.php can be placed one directory above the web root which contains the core wordpress files and you can place your secret in it. Being out of the web root the file is not accessible from the web and its content can not be read even if web server for some reason lets an outsider read the files. I would assume this is a configuration wpengine uses or supports, you should ask them about it.

And wpengine in the end is a shared hosting with all kinds of shared hosting related limitations, and if you just have to have it as an environment variable, maybe you should look for other hosting provider.
